# Changing my email address to name@protonmail.com gets a confirmation email but name@pm.me does not, why?

Tags: support, user-accounts, email

Background: name@pm.me is included (once activated) in a name@protonmail.com account.

I have tried changing my email address to name@pm.me from both Ask Ubuntu and Meta, but neither sent a confirmation email to protonmail. If I change my email address to name@protonmail.com the confirmation email arrives as expected, almost immediately.

I know that the protonmail side is working, as sending other emails (e.g. email address change at chess.com) to the same name@pm.me results in an email at protonmail.

Creating a new account using the name@pm.me format also results in no confirmation email being sent.

What do you think is happening?
Does the Stack Exchange email checking code not like such a short TLD?

Answer (score 8):

The email that was initially sent to your @pm.me address was bounced by the server, and the email was subsequently marked as suppressed due to that (which means future email attempts to the same address get dropped). That is definitely something that occurred on Protonmail's side - only they can bounce a message. If one of them is working, though, we suggest just using that one.

Comment: Thanks for that, can you provide me with any details so I can relay them to protonmail please?

Comment: I can only see that the first message bounced. There isn't additional detail I can provide.

Comment: Understood, thanks. Is there any way to clear the suppression at some point in the future, assuming bouncing issues can be resolved (currently awaiting response from protonmail)?